# Unable to set hidden Property, Protected Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that protects 3 sheets in a single workbook on opening.

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

  Sheets("InputForm").Protect "password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
  Sheets("Invoice").Protect "password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
  Sheets("List").Protect "password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

i also have some code that shows/hides rows based on whether `TRUE/FALSE` in a cell `N14`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   If ActiveSheet.Name = "InputForm" Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Sheets("Invoice").Rows("57:123").Hidden = Range("N14").Value
     Sheets("InputForm").Rows("57:94").Hidden = Range("N14").Value
     Application.EnableEvents = True

Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

When i use a command button to execute some copy/paste code, i get an Error 1004, unable to set the hidden property of the range class. Debugging points to the `Sheets("Invoice")...` line.

However, if i end the debugger and click the button again, it seems to work fine...?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to un-protect your sheets before you can make changes to them - even with VBA - it is the same concept.